# Регулярное выполнение задачи

Tags: php, ubuntu, vkontakte-api

У меня есть игровой бот, там есть эвенты во время которых людям нужно ждать некоторое время (от 10 секунд до нескольких минут). Чтобы в это время получать информацию о таймере, им приходится жать кнопку "обновить".
Чтобы сделать таймер более интерактивным, я могу ботом редактировать сообщение с помощью sleep(1), но мне не нравится так делать.
Я пока что прочитал про cron и sleep(), но похоже что эти функции все же предназначены для других задач. Можно как-то по-другому пробирать массив "работающих" каждую секунду?
php, vkapi, ubuntu

Comment: sleep(1) именно для этого и существует

Comment: Задача выполняется каждую секунду в течении минуты. + есть другие пользователи. Их может быть тысяча. Разве во во время sleep поток не встает?

Comment: Ничто не мешает завести два потока, например

Comment: (хотя если это php, то может сам php и мешает... но в нормальных языках программирования проблем с этим никогда не было)